# How to use system environment variable as part of @PropertySource value?

Tags: java, spring

I want to launch my program with `java ... -Denv=prod ...`
and have

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/settings/$idontknowwhat$/database.properties")`
```

read properties file: `/settings/prod/database.properties`

I have tried using `#{systemProperties['env']}` but it is not resolved with exception:

```
Could not open ServletContext resource ['classpath:/settings/#{systemProperties['env']}/database.properties]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found it, I can simply use

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/settings/${env}/database.properties")
```

Comment: Maven cannot see that ${env} unfortunately, so some other way should be chosen. Maybe Maven conf?

Indeed, where is no maven deploy required, it does the trick.

Comment: How is maven related here? This is about Spring resolving a property source based on the command line parameter supplied during application launch.

Comment: Just wanted to note that this also works for environment variables (System.getenv)