# How can I set my own property file and log file location in spring boot through my own environment variable?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to set both property file (`myproperty.properties`) and log file location (`myLogFile.log`) through my own environment variable name (`MYENV` for example).
property file name must be different from spring boot `application.properties` name and log file has its own name also.
Do not want to use `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location`.

`MYENV` will be set to `"/locationFiles"` value for example. `myproperty.properties` file location is `"/locationFiles/config"` 
and `myLogFile.log` file location is `"/locationFiles/log"`.

I know that I can use the following code snippet for reading my environment variable.
But How do I use `propertiesLocation` below to read the properties data in a simple Spring boot way?
I do not know how to define a corresponding java configuration class as It seems that configuration ppties file path cannot be set in a variable.

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    String propertiesLocation;
    
    private void propertyLocation() {
    this.propertiesLocation = env.getProperty("MYENV")+"/config/";

    }
    
}
```

The following code snippet does not match with what I want to do as I cannot
write something like that : `@PropertySource(env.getProperty("MYENV")+"/config/")`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:myproperty.properties")
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I saw [Environment Specific application.properties file in Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196451/environment-specific-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot-application) but I does not match exactly with what I've described above.
As I want to define my own environment variable name and file names.
And I'm also looking for another way than using `java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path-to-file> myBootProject.jar` as defined in [Spring boot how to read properties file outside jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754459/spring-boot-how-to-read-properties-file-outside-jar).
I want to know if there is an alternative way to this method.

Comment: To access env varables at annotation level try ```#{systemEnvironment['MYENV']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to [How to use system environment variable as part of @PropertySource value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387645/how-to-use-system-environment-variable-as-part-of-propertysource-value) link
I found out my answer using `@PropertySource("file:${MYENV}/config/my.properties")`